# Restrict App Registration access to a specific group

Tags: azure, security, azure-active-directory

I'm building a web app that uses Azure Active Directory has a signin method. In Azure, I'm looking to restrict the access to my app to only a specific group of users. I can't find how to do this in the Azure portal and would appreciate some pointers.

Here's my setup. I want to restraint access of **My Application** to only users that are members of **Group 1**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple single active directory scenario with a paid-for AAD instance (which is what allows you to use groups) you can use the Authentication/Authorization option on the web blade to turn on automatic auth and then use the web app registration to grant the group access. [This is a fairly decent write up](https://msftplayground.com/2017/06/restricting-access-to-your-azure-web-application/).

In a multi-tenant scenario you can take the programmatic approach by [modifying the app registration manifest file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest) to include security groups and then [check membership on the fly as users log in](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/03/13/azure-app-service-authentication-aad-groups/). [Here is an official MS sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims).

Comment: Thanks for the doc. More specifically, I had to go to Enterprise Application->MyApp->Properties->User assignment required (YES)

Answer (score 8):

Although its been a few years since this question was asked, maybe this answer helps someone with the same problem.

I think the best solution would be to follow the steps from this post: https://edi.wang/post/2019/12/13/how-to-allow-only-selected-users-to-access-an-application-in-azure-ad.

Quick summary of the steps after creating the app registration:

1. Go to Azure AD -> Enterprise applications -> YOUR APP -> properties
2. Select Assignment required -> Yes
3. Go to Azure AD -> Enterprise applications -> YOUR APP -> Users and Groups
4. Select the Users and Groups who should be able to login into your app